# Nodejs or node returns nothing on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, azure, ubuntu, npm

I've built a Javascript app running on Node within my MacOS environment, and everything works great.  Now I've created an Azure Ubuntu server, rsync'd the source from my machine.

I've duplicated the app requirements by installing npm, node, and all the packages required.  I SSH into the server and when I run the app from the Ubuntu server via

```
$node app.js
```

All that is returned is

```
$
```

Reading that Ubuntu uses nodejs-legacy, i've also tried

```
$nodejs app.js
```

Same result

```
$node -v
v4.7.2
```

I've also built a package.json file and when executing with

```
npm start
```

it immediately returns back to $.

Comment: How did you install node? On Debian based distros like Ubuntu there is a ham radio software called node. So if you `apt install node` it will install something completely different. You need to `apt install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm`

Comment: Yes, that's how I installed it `$ sudo apt install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (4.7.2~dfsg-1ubuntu3).
nodejs-legacy is already the newest version (4.7.2~dfsg-1ubuntu3).
npm is already the newest version (3.5.2-0ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it wasn't working is the default APT repository that is called when installing nodejs on Ubuntu is outdated.  I ran the following to code to fix the problem.  It automatically uninstalls all the other incorrect packages, sets the correct repository, and re-installs.

```
# Sets up the correct APT repository hosted by NodeSource, and adds the PGP key to the system's APT keychain
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -

# Installs Node.js
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Updates NPM
$ sudo npm install npm --global
```

All apps work as intended now!